# How do I completely uninstall and reinstall MySql without removing packages listed as dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

About a month ago MySql server 8 stopped working on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine. I don't know what caused the problem but I suspect this followed an update. Since then I've scoured the Web for solutions based on the error message, tried and failed with all.

Finally I decided to follow the suggestion to uninstall and reinstall MySql. When I used the command `sudo apt purge mysql*` I was prompted to yes/no to deleting graphics, office and other applications that I use. So I instead used `sudo apt purge mysql-server-8.0`, rebooted the computer and reinstalled.

How do I completely uninstall and reinstall MySql without removing packages listed as dependencies, while keeping my data intact? Here's the console out put from the installation:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0
[sudo] password for mark: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,526 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-8.0 amd64 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1 [1,324 kB]
Fetched 1,324 kB in 1s (1,405 kB/s)         
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 786262 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2021-03-29T13:09:23.808962Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-29 09:09:29 EDT; 18ms ago
    Process: 20673 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 20681 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 20681 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

Mar 29 09:09:29 logwood systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mar 29 09:09:29 logwood systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 29 09:09:29 logwood systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (246.6-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Adding truncated contents of error log:

```
2021-03-29T13:09:36.683551Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) starting as process 20825
2021-03-29T13:09:36.707588Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-29T13:09:36.779014Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2021-03-29T13:09:36.779243Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 65 = ['mercury/pma__relation.ibd', 'nations/countries.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.779489Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 68 = ['mercury/pma__pdf_pages.ibd', 'nations/states.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.779698Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 69 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_login_lockdown.ibd', 'mercury/pma__column_info.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.779914Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 70 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_failed_logins.ibd', 'mercury/pma__history.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.780138Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 71 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_login_activity.ibd', 'mercury/pma__recent.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.780368Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 72 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_global_meta.ibd', 'mercury/pma__favorite.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.780635Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 73 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_events.ibd', 'mercury/pma__table_uiprefs.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.780886Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 74 = ['learningcentre/wp_aiowps_permanent_block.ibd', 'mercury/pma__tracking.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.781143Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 75 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_user_postmeta.ibd', 'mercury/pma__userconfig.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.781451Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 76 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_quiz_attempts.ibd', 'mercury/pma__users.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.781718Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 77 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_product_to_voucher.ibd', 'mercury/pma__usergroups.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.781979Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 78 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_voucher_code_redemptions.ibd', 'mercury/pma__navigationhiding.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.782249Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 79 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_vouchers_codes.ibd', 'mercury/pma__savedsearches.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.782564Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 80 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_notifications.ibd', 'mercury/pma__central_columns.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.782851Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 81 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_events.ibd', 'mercury/pma__designer_settings.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.783144Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 82 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_events_open_sessions.ibd', 'mercury/pma__export_templates.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.783463Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 83 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_sessions.ibd', 'mercury/commission.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.783773Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 84 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_api_keys.ibd', 'mercury/customers.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.784091Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 85 = ['learningcentre/wp_lifterlms_webhooks.ibd', 'mercury/deliverycity.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.784456Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 88 = ['mercury/eventlog.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_customersessions.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.784793Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 91 = ['mercury/packages.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_driversessions.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.785136Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 92 = ['mercury/pickupcity.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_eventlog.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.785520Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 98 = ['mercury/users.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_servicecost.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.785881Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 99 = ['mercury/weight.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_sessions.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.786368Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 100 = ['mercury/zones.ibd', 'mycity/wp_mycity_taxes.ibd'] 
2021-03-29T13:09:36.786829Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2021-03-29T13:09:36.787238Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2021-03-29T13:09:36.787885Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-03-29T13:09:36.788735Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-03-29T13:09:36.790344Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

Comment: can you add contents of  /var/log/mysql/error.log to the question? the failure reason should be in it

Comment: @JanMyszkier, added a section of the error log since it seems the same error repeated several times.